# How to efficiently count one-to-squillion relationships in Mongoose / MongoDB? (e.g. the "like" count for a Tweet on Twitter)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's imagine I'm building an app similar to Twitter just for an easy example (and using Mongoose / MongoDB).

I'd have a collection for "tweets" and my question is: **how can I manage the "like count" for a tweet without putting unnecessary strain on the database?**

My first instinct was to have another collection named "likes" and each document would store the id of the user who liked the tweet, and the id of the tweet they liked.

But then I realized if I want show 20 tweets on the front-end it would take me 21 queries (**this is where I think I'm misunderstanding something basic and it shouldn't take me this many queries**). One query to find the 20 most recent tweets, and another query-per tweet to count how many related "like" documents there are for it. Is there a more efficient way of handling that in MongoDB? Or is this where I'd need to turn to some sort of caching solution in my app?

My next thought was to instead embed a "usersWhoHaveLiked" array within each tweet document like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("abc123abc123"),
    title: "My first tweet",
    author: 3,
    usersWhoHaveLiked: [3, 20, 17, 5]
}
```

But if hundreds of thousands of users can "like" a tweet that array could become incredibly large and I'm worried that modifying an array of that size could be CPU-expensive / slow, or outright overflow the 16mb per document allowed.

I realize there are *many* different ways of architecting this solution, so I'm not looking for a **best** way, which I know would be highly subjective... what makes this quesiton atleast a little bit objective is that we want to minimize stress put on the db & server; which **is** measurable.

I'm a database rookie so if there's a Mongoose / MongoDB flavored way of handling this please feel free to point out things that might be painfully obvious to others :)

Thanks!

Comment: My first instinct is to go to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) of whatever I am using and see if they contain anything that might help. 

Comment: @JasonCust I read through the basics of the docs. In my OP, I was originally leaning towards parent-referencing (one-to-squillions from that blog post) but worried about performing an additional query per-tweet to count how many likes it has... so to display 20 tweets, that's 21 queries? One query to find the 20 most recent tweets, and then another query for each tweet to count how many related likes it has? Is that typical, or is there a more elegant way? I know I'm missing a key concept, just not sure what 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the three types of references stated by Mongo's [blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) on this topic:

### One-to-Few

Generally less than a few hundred items but other factors do have an impact.

A data object for your example might look like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("abc123abc123"),
    title: "My first tweet",
    author: 3,
    usersWhoHaveLiked: [
        { name: 'Foo' }
        { name: 'Bar' }
    ]
}
```

To get the tweet and like count would be one query to mongo and then getting the length of the `usersWhoHaveLiked` array:

```
Tweets.findById('abc123abc123').exec().then((tweet) => {
    const likeCount = tweet.usersWhoHaveLiked.length;
    // do something with tweet and likeCount
});
```

### One-to-Many

Generally "up to several hundred [items], but never more than a couple thousand or so".

A data object for your example might look like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("abc123abc123"),
    title: "My first tweet",
    author: 3,
    usersWhoHaveLiked: [3, 20, 17, 5]
}
```

To get the tweet and like count would be the same as one-to-few:

```
Tweets.findById('abc123abc123').exec().then((tweet) => {
    const likeCount = tweet.usersWhoHaveLiked.length;
    // do something with tweet and likeCount
});
```

### One-to-Squillions

Generally "more than a couple thousand or so".

A data object for your example might look like:

```
// tweet
{
    _id: ObjectId("abc123abc123"),
    title: "My first tweet",
    author: 3
}

// likes
{
    _id: ObjectId("abc123abc124"),
    tweet: ObjectId("abc123abc123"),
    author: 4 // or could be embedded info as well or a mix
}
```

To get the tweet and like count would be two queries:

```
Promise.all([
    Tweets.findById('abc123abc123').exec(),
    Likes.count({ tweet: 'abc123abc123' }).exec()
]).then(([tweet, likeCount]) => {
    // do something with tweet and likeCount
});
```

---

There are some ways to simplify this and I will leave them up to you to explore:

- In the first two examples, create a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) getter that will get the array length for you (i.e. `tweet.likeCount`)
- For the last example, create a [post save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) from `likes` that will update a property on `tweets` (e.g. `likeCount`).

---

A final note regarding when to use which of the three strategies depends on more than just the number of items. A couple other key concerns are if the data needs to stand on it's own and the velocity of change of the array.

Comment: Thanks! I like your idea to use the "post save hook" feature in the "one to squillions" situation - I wasn't aware of that option. I had tried a messier but similar strategy, where I manually incremented / decremented the `likeCount` on each tweet document when a like is created / deleted, but I did this within my "Like" controller... I like the idea of handling it from within Mongoose / the schema instead far more. Overall, it will create an additional query/save when creating/deleting a like, but it will save an extra query each time we display a tweet. Thanks again!